# Minimizing the cost of generating a certain amount of power

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling, operations-research

I am working on electricity generation. I have $n$ motors and must produce a given amount of power:

- Let the rotational speed of the $i$-th motor be denoted by $\omega_i$. For each motor, there is a lower bound and an upper bound on its rotational speed, i.e., $$\omega_i^\min \leq \omega_i \leq \omega_i^\max$$
- Each motor is either active or not. If a motor is active, the given lower and upper bounds must be satisfied. If it is not active, the lower and upper bounds are $0$.

If the $i$-th motor is active, the cost of operating it is $f_i (\omega_i)$, where $\omega_i^\min \leq \omega_i \leq \omega_i^\max$. The function $f_i$ is either linear or quadratic. Let the binary variable $x_i \in \{ 0, 1 \}$ denote whether the $i$-th motor is active ($x_i = 1$) or not. Thus, the total cost to be minimized is

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i f_i (\omega_i)$$

subject to the constraint that enough power be generated

$$ \sum_{i=1} x_i \omega_i \geq \text{required power target} $$

I hope this is understandable. So I need a way/algorithm/paper to solve this and implement this into my code. What constraint should I make?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes. Each speed has its price based on their function. I have to reach a sum(speed) of the motors while their sum(price) will be the lowest

Comment: What is the nature of $f()$? Linear? Quadratic?  Nonconvex? It makes a big difference with respect to available algorithms.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes, I guess, I have to implement it and test it if the maths is correct. I am trying to solve it with matrices and vectors to sum them and the subtract the corresponding value. So far it sounds good for me, but I have to check how much memory does it use

Comment: @prubin They can be Linear or Quadratic aswell

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes, I agree with your edits, thank you. Yes, whether it is active or not, and if active its speed

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo For simplicity speed = power

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo let's assume it can not be out of admissible range. For example: If a motors lower bound is 2000 1/s and its upper bound is 4000 1/s and there is no such thing as 1500 1/s. I know it would not possible in the real world but its like it reaches 2000 1/s from 0 1/s instantly.

Comment: If all the $f_i$ are linear this is a linear programming problem that can be solved using the simplex algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I am still figuring it out.

Comment: @hjbello, not all fi are linear, they can be either linear or quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f(0)=0$, you can reformulate as MILP or MIQP, depending on whether $f_i$ is linear or quadratic, respectively.  Let nonnegative decision variable $y_i$ represent the product $x_i \omega_i$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_i f_i(y_i)$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_i y_i &\ge \text{target} \\
\omega_i^\min x_i \leq y_i &\leq \omega_i^\max x_i &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}

---

If $f(0)\not=0$, you can reformulate as MILP or MIQCQP, depending on whether $f_i$ is linear or quadratic, respectively.  Let nonnegative decision variable $y_i$ represent the product $x_i \omega_i$, and let nonnegative decision variable $z_i$ represent the product $x_i f_i(\omega_i)$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_i z_i$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_i y_i &\ge \text{target} \tag1\label1\\
\omega_i^\min \leq \omega_i &\leq \omega_i^\max &&\text{for all $i$} \tag2\label2\\
\omega_i^\min x_i \leq y_i &\leq \omega_i^\max x_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag3\label3\\
\omega_i^\min (1-x_i) \leq \omega_i - y_i &\leq \omega_i^\max (1-x_i) &&\text{for all $i$} \tag4\label4\\
f_i(\omega_i) - z_i &\leq M_i(1 - x_i) &&\text{for all $i$} \tag5\label5
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{3} enforces $x_i = 0 \implies y_i = 0$.
Constraint \eqref{4} enforces $x_i = 1 \implies y_i = \omega_i$.
Constraint \eqref{5} enforces $x_i = 1 \implies z_i \ge f_i(\omega_i)$.

Comment: Unfortonately f(0) not equals 0, so I can not use this, if I am correct